# when hover an element but does not affect other element transition property

Tags: css, inheritance, css-transitions

I am trying to reveal my `p` text it doesn't using transition.
I'm trying to resolve it from hour but does not understand why it's not working.

```css
.section-about--card {
  width:100%;
  height: 15rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: all 1s linear; 
  & .about-card--details {  
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  &:hover .about-card--details{
    height:50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="section-about--card">
  <p class="about-card--details">
    some text
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: are you trying to make the some text p bigger font?

Comment: @KickButtowski actually  i'm trying to make dropdown kind thing its working but the transition effect is not working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS `Transition` will [not be inherited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition#formal_definition) by child elements. Add the transition to the child `.about-card--details`.

```css
.section-about--card {
  width:100%;
  height: 15rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
  & .about-card--details {  
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
    transition: all 1s linear; 
  }
  &:hover .about-card--details{
    height:50px;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="section-about--card">
    <p class="about-card--details">
      some text
    </p>
  </div>
```

Comment: when i try this its didn't work but now its working, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you want to either make the font of the text bigger or you want to make the height of the text container bigger.

lets cover both situation:

in your example, you just need to add background color to .about-card--details like `background-color: yellow;` to make it more **noticeable**

and you have your transition on the wrong spot
please move `transition: all 1s linear;`  to `& .about-card--details`  becasue you want  transition to be done on `.about-card--details`

second sitution if you want to make the font bigger you simply do the following:

```
.section-about--card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15rem;
  border: 1px solid black;

  .about-card--details {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    height: 10px;
    transition: all 1s ease;

    &:hover {
      height: 50px;
      font-size: 50px;
      background-color: yellow;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: bro i think you didn't get it i am trying to create a dropdown but when i hover it does use 1 second transition. later i added transition in hover and start working.

Comment: happy you found the answer

Comment: but I mentioned your transition is in wrong place fyi

Comment: yeah, i forgot to credits to you. thanks for your help too.